# Where is the manpage of the set builtin?

Tags: command-line, bash

When I type the command

```
man set
```

It gives the postgresql 9.3.6 manpage documentation of the set command. (May be I need to precise that I have postgres installed in my machine). However, I am not interested in the set command found in postgres but the built in set command. My question is how can I view the man page of the built in set command?

Comment: use: `help -m set | less`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To obtain help on a `bash` built-in such as `set`, use:

```
help set
```

Or else, run `man bash` and search on `set`.

#### Documentation

To learn more about `help`, run `help help`:

```
$ help help
help: help [-dms] [pattern ...]
    Display information about builtin commands.

    Displays brief summaries of builtin commands.  If PATTERN is
    specified, gives detailed help on all commands matching PATTERN,
    otherwise the list of help topics is printed.

    Options:
      -d        output short description for each topic
      -m        display usage in pseudo-manpage format
      -s        output only a short usage synopsis for each topic matching
        PATTERN

    Arguments:
      PATTERN   Pattern specifiying a help topic

    Exit Status:
    Returns success unless PATTERN is not found or an invalid option is given.
```